# prove that if U is a subspace of the finite dimensional vector space V such that dimU=dimV then U=V

Tags: linear-algebra

prove that if U is a subspace of the finite dimensional vector space V such that dimU=dimV then U=V

I try with the following

let dim U = dim V = n.

∴thhere are n independent vectors u1, u2, u3, ...un in Usuch that span{u1, u2,..un}=U.

∴u1, u2, u3, ...un are independent in V also as U is asubset of V.

∴u1, u2, u3, ...un form a basis of V as dim V =n.

∴u1, u2,...un span V

∴U=V

but not sure if this way correct or not

Answer (score 1):

Your solution can't be right since you don't use finite dimensionality anywhere. So if this argument was correct it would prove the same result also for infinite dimensional spaces, but that is not true.

Try to be very precise about the argument you use. Refer to the actual theorems and be very precise. Try to pinpoint where precisely does finite dimensionality come into the picture.

Comment: If the OP has already proved that a set of $n$ linearly independent vectors in a space of (finite) dimension $n$ is a basis, then the OP’s argument is fine. Finite dimensionality is implicit in the notation $\{u_1,u_2,\ldots,u_n\}$.

Comment: Yes. I think (and that is what I was trying to hint to OP) that precisely that property uses finite dimensionality and must be stated explicitly in the proof.

Comment: As far as I’m concerned, whether it must be stated explicitly depends on what is already known and permitted to be assumed.